# How Do I Know Which Icon I Used In draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I used an Azure icon collection in draw.io/diagrams.net to make my diagram.

I loaded the icons following [this post](https://www.moderndata.ai/2020/08/working-with-azure-icons-in-draw-io-diagrams-net/). You can open the design page with the icons loaded by following [this link](https://app.diagrams.net/?splash=0&libs=general&clibs=Uhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/DaveRuijter/diagrams.net/master/1.%20Azure%20Icon%20Set;Uhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/DaveRuijter/diagrams.net/master/2.%20Azure%20Docs).

When I initially selected the icon in the sidebar it had a description of what it was.

When I add it to the page though, I can't see the name of the icon anymore, which makes it hard to tell which icon I used without making a good guess and scanning through the libraries.

Am I missing something? How do I tell which icon/shape I added?

**EDIT:** Following the comment I added a few items.

Adding a General Shape - Ellipse and pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>  I see;

```
ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;
```

For the built in Azure collection adding a "DNS Zones" I see:

```
aspect=fixed;html=1;points=[];align=center;image;fontSize=12;image=img/lib/azure2/networking/DNS_Zones.svg;
```

For the external collection "1. Azure Icon Set - DNS-Zones" I see:

```
shape=image;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;imageAspect=0;aspect=fixed;image=data:image/svg+xml,PHN2Z....ProbablyEmbeddedSVG
```

Ideally, I would like to hover over the icon on the page and see the same pop-up that I see when I hover over the icon in the Shapes Panel.

Answer (score 2):

If you select an icon and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, you should see additional code. Do you see a icon name also under "shape ="?

If not, please attach a print screen of it and the code so we could check if something can be done to improve this.

Comment: I updated the question with the code. You should be able to reproduce it without a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. I added this to our GitHub so you could track the progress https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1893 At the moment, Ctrl+e is the closest we have.